# Xamarin.iOS: How to skip backward/forward in AVPlayer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avplayer

Self explanatory title, what is the best way to skip forward and backward by 10 seconds in an AVPlayer in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. This skips forward, swap out the `+` for a `-` to skip backward.

```
_audioPlayer.Seek(new CoreMedia.CMTime(
        (long)_audioPlayer.CurrentTime.Seconds + 10,
        _audioPlayer.CurrentTime.TimeScale
    ));
```